# What's the best way to configure the containers to have an IP directly on the LAN

Tags: networking, network-bridge, lxc

I see that there are a lot of new ease-of-use improvements to LXC in 12.04 & 12.10, and although I see some description to setting up bridged networking such that my containers have their own LAN IP, I have the sneaky feeling that maybe there's a "simpler" way in ubuntu 12.10 now?

- http://lxc.sourceforge.net/index.php/about/kernel-namespaces/network/configuration/

I didn't quite grasp it from the ubuntu server docs. Could anyone help me know which path is best to follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a bridge is a pretty simple process.

A key points to be aware of:

- Your NIC needs to be run in promiscuous mode for the bridge to work, promiscuous mode isn't supported on many wifi nic's, hence there's no way to make this work on many wifi NICs (check support for promiscuous mode if you need it).

---

```
Edit /etc/network/interfaces

Add:
# Bridge for LXC containers
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_maxwait 0

sudo service networking restart

Configure network in LXC config as:
lxc.network.type=veth
lxc.network.link=br0
lxc.network.flags=up
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.0.2.215/24
lxc.network.name = eth0

lxc-start -n <CN>
```

Comment: Does running the NIC in promiscuous mode mean that the container can see access network traffic promiscuously?